# Realtek HD Audio Manager notification titles change to Microsoft.Explorer.Notification.{80FC1ED3-0B71-3750-F939}

Tags: windows-10, notifications, realtek-hd-audio

On my main laptop (Windows 10), I have Realtek HD Audio Manger (from factory). Sometimes, when it gives me a notification saying I have plugged/unplugged a device from the audio jack, it sometimes reads `Realtek HD Audio Manager` and sometimes reads `Microsoft.Explorer.Notification.{80FC1ED3-0B71-3750-F939}` (I think that is right, I can't read it after F939). The HEX translation makes no sense (I didn't expect it to), because it reads `���q7P�9`. Is this perhaps an ID for Realtek HD Audio Manager?